# Why numba parallel is slower when using more threads in some cases?

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, numba

I would like to post another example of numba thread problem that I do not know how to solve. It's a very simple problem that calculates in parallel the inverse of block matrices.

```
from numpy import empty,float64
from numpy.linalg import inv
from numba import njit, prange,set_num_threads
@njit(parallel=True)
def tester1(A,m,n):
    inv_Lambda_p=empty((n,m,m),dtype=float64)
    for i in prange(n):
        inv_Lambda_p[i]=inv(ascontiguousarray(A[i]))
```

```
A=np.random.rand(1000000,10,10)
m=10
n=1000000
inv_a=tester1(A,m,n)
for i in range (16):
    print("Thread ",i+1)
    set_num_threads(i+1)
    %timeit tester1(A,m,n)
```

Results

```
Thread  1
1.72 s ± 9.09 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
Thread  2
932 ms ± 32.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
Thread  3
680 ms ± 15.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
Thread  4
573 ms ± 13 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
Thread  5
555 ms ± 8.73 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
Thread  6
530 ms ± 4.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
Thread  7
511 ms ± 6.14 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
Thread  8
492 ms ± 4.15 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
Thread  9
478 ms ± 5.19 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
Thread  10
471 ms ± 4.37 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
Thread  11
498 ms ± 4.75 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
Thread  12
451 ms ± 1.82 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
Thread  13
442 ms ± 2.24 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
Thread  14
431 ms ± 3.37 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
Thread  15
421 ms ± 3.66 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
Thread  16
442 ms ± 4.77 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Why the times for more threads are slower for less? For instance look for 15 to 16 threads. Is this normal and why? My cpu is 8 cores 16 threads 3.7GHz 16 MB cache, Ram 16gb. Also my cpu is cooled by hydro cooling system.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be due to **allocations** that does not scale in parallel. One solution is to rewrite this using a Gauss-Jordan elimination and take care not to allocate too many arrays. Here is an implementation:

```py
@nb.njit('(float64[:,::1], float64[:,::1])', fastmath=True)
def gaussJordan(mat, out):
    assert mat.shape[0] == mat.shape[1]
    n = mat.shape[0]

    tmpMat = np.zeros((n, 2*n))

    # Copy the input matrix
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            tmpMat[i, j] = mat[i, j]
 
    # Extends the matrix
    for i in range(n):
        tmpMat[i, n+i] = 1.0
 
    # Pivot
    for i in range(n - 1, 0, -1):
        if tmpMat[i - 1, 0] < tmpMat[i, 0]:
            for j in range(2*n):
                temp = tmpMat[i, j]
                tmpMat[i, j] = tmpMat[i - 1, j]
                tmpMat[i - 1, j] = temp

    # Actual elimination
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if j != i:
                temp = tmpMat[j, i] / tmpMat[i, i]
                for k in range(2 * n):
                    tmpMat[j, k] -= tmpMat[i, k] * temp
 
    # Rescaling and copy back to the output matrix
    for i in range(n):
        temp = 1.0 / tmpMat[i, i]
        for j in range(n):
            out[i, j] = tmpMat[i, n+j] * temp

@njit('(float64[:, :, :],)', parallel=True, fastmath=True)
def fastInv(mat):
    assert mat.shape[1] == mat.shape[2]
    n, m = mat.shape[0:2]
    mat2 = np.ascontiguousarray(mat)
    inv_Lambda_p = np.empty((n, m, m), dtype=np.float64)
    for i in nb.prange(n):
        gaussJordan(mat2[i], inv_Lambda_p[i])
    return inv_Lambda_p

A=np.random.rand(1000000,10,10)
m=10
n=1000000
inv_a=fastInv(A)
for i in range(6):
    print("Thread ",i+1)
    set_num_threads(i+1)
    %timeit fastInv(A)
```

The code performs only one allocation per iteration which should be enough for your use-case. The `np.ascontiguousarray` is done once so to avoid many allocations if the array is not contiguous.

Here are results on my 6-core machine:

```
OLD VERSION:

Thread  1
2.26 s ± 6.79 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
Thread  2
1.34 s ± 12.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
Thread  3
1.07 s ± 2.29 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
Thread  4
945 ms ± 7.04 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
Thread  5
865 ms ± 2.36 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
Thread  6
832 ms ± 4.32 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)


NEW VERSION:

Thread  1
2.4 s ± 13.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
Thread  2
1.26 s ± 3.09 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
Thread  3
868 ms ± 4.89 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
Thread  4
667 ms ± 2.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
Thread  5
551 ms ± 4.38 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
Thread  6
487 ms ± 6.33 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Note that while the sequential version is a bit slower, the parallel implementation is 4.92 times faster which is pretty good. In fact, Intel processors like mine (i5-9600KF) reduce a bit the frequency when many cores are running (especially when packed SIMD AVX2 instructions are used): in parallel the frequency switch from 4.5 GHz to 4.3 GHz causing the optimal scaling to be `6 / (4.5 / 4.3) = 5.73`. I guess the scaling can be a bit better without the allocation in each iteration but this is hard to do better in Numba (there is an optimization in Numba so to allocate the array once in each thread if the code is inlined but the code is surprisingly much slower when this is done).

Note that the Gauss-Jordan elimination may not be as accurate as the Numpy method (which AFAIK use a LU factorization in log space in this case) but it should be fine with 10x10 matrices (as long as the input values in `A` are also reasonable).

Finally, note that since your processor have 8 cores and 16 threads, the computation cannot be faster than 8 times for heavily computing operations like this. Hardware threads just improve the core usage by saturating more but they are not actual cores. They can only speed up the code more if computing units are not saturated which should be the case if the code is efficiently implemented. Hardware cores are typically useful to speed up *latency-bound* codes operating on the main memory for example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The inversion I am forced to do it by the numpy.linalg.inv() function. Also I ran this code for my processor for 16 threads and I get: 
`Thread  15
357 ms ± 6.71 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
Thread  16
364 ms ± 8.71 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`
Can this be done with the inv function?

Comment: Is the array actually contiguous? If your input array is contiguous then, no, `numpy.linalg.inv` is the problem so you cannot speed up the computation using it. You can provide the whole matrix to it but it is slower in practice (it looks like Numpy/Numba does a naive loop internally with expensive allocations in this case because standard BLAS libraries certainly do not support batch matrix inversion). If your input is not contiguous, then the calls to `np.ascontiguousarray` may be suboptimal and reduce the scalability too.

Comment: I added a note regarding hardware thread so to explain why you should not expect a 16x speed up. By the way, what is your actual processor reference? If you are running on Alder Lake processors (or any Big-Little processors like the Apple M1 for example), then it is normal it does not scale. Ha and one need to care about the turbo-boost on Intel processor too (as it affect the optimal scalability).

Comment: My processor is ryzen 7 2700x. Also I know that I cannot expect a 16x speed up. My problem was the fact that using more cores gives worse times than using less in some cases. I tried with not using np.ascontiguousarray but I had the same problem. So you say that the problem is with the inv function of numpy? Or maybe it's also something else?

Comment: Would this problem be easier to be solved in c++ or using cython? Is python not good enough?